# Bootstrap navbar not rendering in IE11 when served from IIS, but OK in iis-express

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iis, navbar, iis-express

I have a really weird case that's driving me nuts! I've pared a page that uses a Bootstrap navbar back to the bare minimum.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Data <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Data1">Data 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Data2">Data 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the page from within Visual Studio, using local iisexpress, it renders perfectly fine in both IE11 and Chrome.

However, when I move the page to a Windows Server running IIS, it renders fine in Chrome but is messed up in IE11.

[image]

Only the three bar small navigation icon is displayed in IE11, regardless of browser window size. Clicking on the navbar has no effect.

If I use remote desktop to access the web server and load the page locally (localhost), it renders fine in IE11. The issue relates only to viewing the page in IE11 when served remotely.

With both Chrome and IE11, I've tried deleting the browser cache and watched in Fiddler as the html, css and js files are requested and all looks OK. All files are returned OK with a status code 200.

It can't be an IE11 issue per se, as the page loads and runs OK in IE11 when launched from VS + iisexpress locally. But not from IIS.

It works fine in Chrome from both IIS and iisexpress.

Any ideas, as I've run out of them.

Doug

Comment: I've discovered one more interesting thing. If I remote desktop to the IIS web server and open the page in IE11 then http://localhost/home.html works perfectly fine, but http://servername/home.html is messed up as above.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason for the behavior. It was the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting in IE.

I added the meta tag

```html
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

And now all works fine.